# How can I wrap my input field with a <div> tag when using with Symfony formbuilder?

Tags: php, symfony, oop, formbuilder

I am creating an input field with Symfony:

```
$formBuilder->add($field['fieldName'], TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')));
```

The output is:

```
<input type="text" id="form_color" name="form[color]" class="form-control">
```

The output I would need is:

```html
<div class="cp input-group colorpicker-component">
<input type="text" id="form_color" name="form[color]" class="form-control" /> <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
</div>
```

This means I somehow have to add a parent to the specific form field.
I cannot add it to the actual form, because this parent div is only added to the field in specific cases. Is there a way to do it in the formbuilder?

Comment: Are you going to apply it only to some text fields within a form? To all text-fields within one form? to all text-fields in all forms in your application?

Comment: Only to some text-fields in one form. In case of field type or field name is color

Comment: Yes, it is a text field. I just want to add bootstrap color picker https://farbelous.io/bootstrap-colorpicker/v2/

Comment: I don't want to use color field by symfony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create my own [custom field type](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html) to handle these fields.

First define the field class

```php
// src/Form/Type/ColorSelectorType.php
namespace App\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class ColorSelectorType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return TextType::class;
    }
}
```

Then you'll need to create the template for the field:

```
{# templates/form/fields.html.twig #}
{% block color_selector_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
       <div class="cp input-group colorpicker-component">
            <input{{ block('widget_container_attributes') }} />
                 <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
       </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

Register your custom templates:

```
# config/packages/twig.yaml
twig:
    form_themes:
        - 'form/fields.html.twig'
```

And finally use your new field:

```php
$formBuilder->add($field['fieldName'], ColorSelectorType::class);
```

Logically, you'll need to customize this to suit your needs, but it should be enough to get you going.